# can access 2010 open a 2003 database that has the old mdw security

Tags: ms-access

can access 2010 open a 2003 database that has the old mdw security

Comment: Both A2007 and A2010 use the Jet 4 database engine for MDB-format files, and the newer ACE for ACCDBs. Thus, since you're using the legacy db engine, it supports all the legacy ULS features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although User Level Security is not supported for the new ACCDB database format, Access 2010 (just like Access 2007) can still use it with MDB format databases.  See what Microsoft has to say on this topic: [Introduction to Access 2010 security](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-access-2010-security-HA010341741.aspx)

Comment: I've recently figured out that it's not a file format thing -- A2007/A2010 are actually using Jet 4 instead of the ACE for working with MDBs. This can be shown by examining the default DAO reference in an MDB created by A2007/A2010 -- it's set to DAO 3.6, which means its using Jet 4, and not ACE.